# Generating EDI files (CMS1500 Form)

Tags: java, edi

I am working on an Health record system. We have to generate electronic claims(CMS1500 Form) for billing purposes and all the data required to generate the claim is there in our database. The insurance carriers take the EDI format files to process claims. So how can I generate an EDI file with HIPAA standards. What I wish that is there a tool or framework which makes me to map the particular columns from my database table in order to generate the EDI file?

I am using java and mysql.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool!  (Actually, there's quite a few of them)

Commercial translators exist to help you with this process.  In your case, I recommend [Liaison Delta](http://liaison.com/products/transform/delta) and [ECS](http://liaison.com/products/integrate/ecs) to handle it.  You can connect your mysql database as your "source" and then an 837 EDI document as your target.  Drag-drop columns to EDI elements, use variables in your map for counters and more, do database lookups on the fly, use built-in date functions.  Obviously there is more to it.

If you are new to EDI, some of the HIPAA documents can be complex with many hierarchical loops, so you are going to have a bit of a learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

For the java platform, there is one by American Coders, http://www.americancoders.com/

Or, you can use MapForce to map EDI files and then have it generate the java code for you.